# Running into error when launching spot instance request with IAM account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create spot EC2 instance with IAM user account.

I got this error message and I can't go further

```
Parameter: SpotFleetRequestConfig.IamFleetRole is invalid.
```

It seems like administrator account needs to give some "policy" or "role" as permission to my IAM.

What "policy" or "role" does admin account give to my IAM?

Answer (score 3):

I think the key things you are looking for are in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#spot-fleet-prerequisites).  Basically, the Role should have the `AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole` service role and allow the `spotfleet.amazonaws.com` service assume the role.

Comment: Followed the docs, created the policy, attached it to the user in question: same error. Even tried our root admin user account: same error.

Answer (score 1):

In the spot request console, you are using defaults which point to the other role.
Please change the role to `AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet` and it should work fine.